# How to limit Nearby Messages to DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I've read the documentation, and as far as I know, I'm correctly using DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT:

```
Strategy strategy = new Strategy.Builder().setDistanceType(DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT).build();

SubscribeOptions subscribeOptions = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
  .setStrategy(strategy)
  .build();
Nearby.Messages.subscribe(googleApiClient, messageListener, subscribeOptions);

PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions.Builder()
  .setStrategy(strategy)
  .build();
Nearby.Messages.publish(googleApiClient, message, publishOptions);
```

It always seems to have the same range as a regular message. I can be in another room, the far side of the house, outdoors, next door--it still seems to go through.

Am I doing something wrong, is there something I can be doing differently to make Nearby Messages limit themselves to a short range? Or is DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT broken?

Comment: The device link may be cached for a short period of time. Can you give details about your test? Does the message go through after waiting a few minutes (maybe try 10 minutes), for example?

Comment: The message always goes through--in regular mode, not Earshot. I thought I had tested it starting an app that would only subscribe and publish with earshot, but I'll try again when I get time.